# JavaFx Project Exception with command line

Tags: java, javafx, command-line

My JavaFx project works well in Intellij IDEA but when I compile and run them with command line, some problem came out
The error is as below:
[here is the screenshot of exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqvbq.png)

Here is my Main class:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Ozlympic.fxml"));

    //controller
    loader.setController(new OzlympicController());

    Parent root =loader.load();

    primaryStage.setTitle("Ozlympic");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, selectOptionException {
    //show the main stage, can not be commented
    launch(args);

    //get all athletes attend the game
    ArrayList<Participates> participates=readTXTData.seperateData();

    Driver driver = new Driver(participates);

    //driver.mainMenu();

}
```

Here is my Ozlympic.fxml file

```
<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="750.0" prefWidth="974.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <TabPane prefHeight="750.0" prefWidth="974.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
        <tabs>
            <Tab fx:id="swimTab" closable="false" text="Swim">
                <fx:include source="Swim.fxml"/>
            </Tab>
            <Tab fx:id="runTab" closable="false" text="Run">
                <fx:include source="Run.fxml"/>
            </Tab>
            <Tab fx:id="cycleTab" closable="false" text="Cycle">
                <fx:include source="Cycle.fxml"/>
            </Tab>
        </tabs>
      </TabPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

And it said there is some problem in swim.fxml too
So here is my swim.fxml and controller

```
<AnchorPane fx:id="swimPane" prefHeight="703.0" prefWidth="974.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8"
            xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="SwimController">
   <Label alignment="CENTER" layoutX="528.0" layoutY="40.0" prefHeight="44.0" prefWidth="320.0"
          text="Here is the results of swim game" textAlignment="CENTER">
      <font>
         <Font name="Arial Bold" size="19.0"/>
      </font>
   </Label>
   <ListView fx:id="swimResult" layoutX="480.0" layoutY="107.0" prefHeight="477.0" prefWidth="439.0"/>
   <Label layoutX="49.0" layoutY="51.0" text="Choose the Athlete attend the swim (4-8)">
      <font>
         <Font name="Arial Bold" size="19.0"/>
      </font>
   </Label>
   <Group layoutX="-6.0" layoutY="110.0">
      <CheckBox fx:id="athlete9" layoutX="265.0" layoutY="209.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="18.0"
                prefWidth="167.0" text="CheckBox"/>
      .....
```

Here is the controller:

```
public class SwimController  implements Initializable{

    @FXML public static CheckBox athlete1;
    @FXML public static CheckBox athlete2;
    @FXML public static CheckBox athlete3;
    @FXML public static CheckBox athlete4;
    @FXML public static CheckBox athlete5;
    @FXML public static CheckBox athlete6;
    @FXML public static CheckBox athlete7;
    @FXML public static CheckBox athlete8;
    @FXML public static CheckBox athlete9;
    @FXML public static CheckBox athlete10;
    @FXML public static CheckBox athlete11;
    @FXML public static CheckBox athlete12;

    @FXML public static Button btnExit;
    @FXML public static Button btnSave;
    @FXML public static Button btnStartGame;

    @FXML public static ListView swimResult;
    @FXML  public AnchorPane swimPane;


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

    }

    @FXML private void btnExitAction(){
        System.out.println("Exit button pressed!");
    }

    @FXML private void btnSaveAction(){
        System.out.println("Save button pressed!");
    }

    @FXML private void btnStartGameAction(){
        System.out.println("Start button pressed!");
    }

    @FXML public static Button generateAthlete;
    @FXML private void btnGenerateAction(){
        System.out.println("Generate button pressed!");
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for helping me !

Comment: Post the stack trace as text (format it as code), not as an image. The exception is pretty self-explanatory: the FXML loader cannot find the controller class. Is `SwimController` in a package?

Comment: I fixed this, I didn't compile all files in this project ... all good XD